# Mysql + where clause matching multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  image_id  style_id
------------------------
1   45        24        
1   45        25        
1   47        25        
1   45        27        
1   45        28
```

I want to pull image_id column where all three below conditions match:

```
style_id = 24
style_id = 25
style_id = 27
```

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT image_id FROM list WHERE (style_id = 24 AND style_id = 25 AND style_id = 27)
```

which doesn't return me image_id 45.

Comment: The query you've written doesn't make much sense - how can 1 row's column have 3 different values, i.e. be equal to `24`, `25` and `27` at the same time?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT image_id 
FROM list 
WHERE style_id IN (24, 25, 27)
GROUP BY image_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT style_id) = 3
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword is only necessary in case you can have duplicate values of `style_id` field per `image_id`.