# MYSQL return 'CombinationID' from set of rows where all rows meet the given criteria EXACTLY

Tags: mysql

Been stumbling on this for ages and can't seem to find out how to do this.

See this table:

[image]

I need to know the DimCombinationID that has EXACTLY the rows where for instance (dim = 100 and DimValue = 395) AND (dim = 900 and DimValue = 281) AND (dim = 600 and DimValue = 342).

So the answer is the DimCombinationID which has 3 rows that exactly match the given criteria. In this case, the DimCombinationID is 22.

The number of criteria can change, so for instance it might just be (dim = 100 and DimValue = 395) -> I need to have the DimCombinationID that just has one row and that row is conform the given criterium of dim = 100 and DimValue = 395.

DimCombinationIDs that have more or less rows than the given number of criteria or not all criteria are met are to not be in the result set.

I've tried loads of queries but I can't seem to get it.

One for instance was:

```
SELECT DimCombinationID FROM dimcombinations WHERE DimCombinationID IN (

    SELECT DimCombinationID FROM dimcombinations
    WHERE
        (Dim = '100' AND DimValue = '395') OR
        (Dim = '600' AND DimValue = '342') OR
        (Dim = '900' AND DimValue = '281') 

    GROUP BY DimCombinationID

    HAVING COUNT(DimCombinationID) = 3
)
GROUP BY DimCombinationID
```

But however I write this query, it either matches wrong or presents the wrong combinationID. This particular query might be 80% right, it's not 100%.

Maybe someone here can help me?

I've found this question and answer but although helpful, I still can't see the light....
[Mysql + where clause matching multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014390/mysql-where-clause-matching-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the combination of `Dim` and `DimValue` for each `DimCombinationID` is unique, you can do this:

```
SELECT DimCombinationID 
FROM dimcombinations
GROUP BY DimCombinationID
HAVING SUM(
  (Dim = '100' AND DimValue = '395') OR
  (Dim = '600' AND DimValue = '342') OR
  (Dim = '900' AND DimValue = '281') 
) = 3 
AND 
COUNT(*) = 3
```

Comment: Inverted commas are for decoration, but otherwise, this rocks

Comment: Tried several combinations with your query and it seems to do exactly what I want. Nice and elegant! Thanks very much forpas!